# The best word to describe my mind picture

Tags: single-word-requests

Say I have made a picture in my mind about the qualities of a person. So I want a word to address my mental picture. For example, John performed all the tasks that he has planned. Here `planned` indicates that he beforehand has jot down the tasks. Similarly, when I jot down some qualities in my mind, I want to refer it. 
The word can be something around illusion, ideal.
In short: How can I express the word `mental picture` more sophisticated manner.

Comment: I have a feeling that "on my mind" does not [mean what you think it does](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-sth-on-your-mind). But sometimes, expressions can't be substituted by a single word. Here, it would be "people I'm concerned about".

Comment: I don't mean that what is on my mind is exactly to be present rather I want a word for 'my mental picture'. If a word doesn't suffice, suggest me some sentence that will reflect `I long to meet with people that my mind has pictured`

Comment: Raida, the real problem here is the meaning in any language, not the wording in English. 
*I long to meet with people that my mind has pictured* is a very difficult concept. 
May we reduce it to *I long to meet people my mind has pictured* and that to *I long to meet people I have pictured*? 
Broadly, those all mean *I long to meet people I’ve specified I’d like to meet*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for **[imagine](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+imagine):**

> form a mental image or concept of.
>
> *"imagine a road trip from Philadelphia to Chicago"*
>
> **synonyms:** visualize, envisage, envision, picture, see in the mind's eye; dream up, think up/of, conjure up, conceive,
>   conceptualize; *formal* ideate
>
> *"imagine sitting through five hours of steady air turbulence"*

In your case, you might say something like:

- *"I **imagined** that John was tall."*

See also: **[imagination](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+imagination):**

> the faculty or action of forming new ideas, or images or concepts of
>   external objects not present to the senses.
>
> *"she'd never been blessed with a vivid imagination"*
>
> **synonyms:** creative power, fancy, vision; informalmind's eye
>
> *"a vivid imagination"*
>
> interest, fascination, attention, passion, curiosity
>
> *"the album captured the public's imagination"*
>
> the ability of the mind to be creative or resourceful.
>
> *"technology gives workers the chance to use their imagination"*
>
> **synonyms:** creativity, imaginativeness, creativeness; vision, inspiration, inventiveness, invention, resourcefulness, ingenuity;
>   originality, innovation, innovativeness
>
> *"you need imagination in dealing with these problems"*
>
> the part of the mind that imagines things.
>
> *"a girl who existed only in my imagination"*

An example might be:

- *"In my **imagination**, Suzy had red hair."*

Try looking these words up in a thesaurus for a bunch of synonyms.

Comment: Thank You for your answer which gave me possible best words to fit in my sentence. I came up with envisage as the best fit word since it quitely reflects my requirement. `Envisage: form a mental picture of (something not yet existing or known).`

Answer (score 0):

The wording of this question is a bit confusing. The only word that comes to mind is envision.

Envision

verb (used with object)

to picture mentally, especially some future event or events: to envision a bright future.

"I long to meet the type of people I have envisioned."

This still feels like an odd way to express the idea, but it's the best suggestion I've got.